# updateChildValues() does not work, but setValue() does

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to implement fan out and here is the problem: When I'm trying to `updateChildValues` in my `usersOrdersRef` reference, it just does nothing. I expect it to create the `user_orders` node, and child node with my `userid` and put a value there.

If I use `setValues` instead, it works fine, but I need to add values without deleting all previous data. What am I doing wrong?

Code:

```
for item in orderArray {
    let childRef = ref.child(item.date!)

    //this works fine
    childRef.updateChildValues(item.convertToDictionary() as! [AnyHashable : Any]) { [unowned self] (error, reference) in
        if error != nil {
            print(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))
        }

        let usersOrdersRef = Database.database().reference().child("users-orders").child(self.appUser.uid)
        var primary = false
        if (item.precursor == "") { primary = true }

        //this does not work, but if i use "setValue" instead it will store data
        usersOrdersRef.updateChildValues([item.date : primary])
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem:

```
//this does not work, but if i use "setValue" instead it will store data
    usersOrdersRef.updateChildValues([item.date : primary])
```

I found myself in the same situation.

The problem was the **data type of the key**. When I casted the key to a String it started to function.

Hope this helps someone in the same situation.

Comment: Many thanks i have been trying to figure out this issue for 2 hours.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem

If I use

> let newHashTagRef = Api.HashTag.REF_HASHTAG.child(word.lowercased())
>                   newHashTagRef.**updateChildValues**([newPostId: true])

=> not working

when I replace

> let newHashTagRef = Api.HashTag.REF_HASHTAG.child(word.lowercased())
>                   newHashTagRef.**setValues**([newPostId: true])

=> it works but it will delete all previous data

Solution

> let newHashTagRef =
>   Api.HashTag.REF_HASHTAG.child(word.lowercased()).**child(newPostId)**
>                   newHashTagRef.**setValue(true)**

Answer (score 0):

I resolve it by myself , now it works like this

`let usersOrdersRef = Database.database().reference().child("users-orders").child(self.appUser.uid).child(item.date!)
                var primary = false
                if (item.precursor == "") { primary = true }
                usersOrdersRef.setValue(primary)`

In that case setValue does not delete all previous data, just adds new

Answer (score 0):

You just need to cast your optional data key into the `updateChildValues` function.

**Updated Code:**

```
for item in orderArray {
    let childRef = ref.child(item.date!)

    //this works fine
    childRef.updateChildValues(item.convertToDictionary() as! [AnyHashable : Any]) { [unowned self] (error, reference) in
        if error != nil {
            print(String(describing: error?.localizedDescription))
        }

        let usersOrdersRef = Database.database().reference().child("users-orders").child(self.appUser.uid)
        var primary = false
        if (item.precursor == "") { primary = true }

        // this will work now, as we have explicity cast the key
        usersOrdersRef.updateChildValues([item.date! : primary])
    }
}
```